# Displaying values from a character vector as italic labels in boxplot in R

Tags: r, boxplot, plotmath

I want to use a character vector for boxplot names, how can I get these to be displayed as italic?

```
# get some data
x <- rnorm(1000)

# I want to get this:
labels <- c(expression(italic("One"), italic("Two")))
labels

boxplot(split(x, cut(x,breaks = c(-Inf, 0, Inf))), names = labels)
```

But using a character vector, such as

```
sNames <- c("One", "Two")
```

I've tried `bquote()`, `expression()` ...

```
labels <- bquote(expression(italic(.(sNames))))
labels # but this is length 1, not 2
```

... and with `sapply()`

```
labels <- sapply(sNames, function(x) bquote(expression(italic(.(x)))))
labels

boxplot(split(x, cut(x,breaks = c(-Inf, 0, Inf))), names = labels)
```

but this doesn't seem to be interpreted as an expression.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create the following function and use it as shown:

```
make.italic <- function(x) as.expression(lapply(x, function(y) bquote(italic(.(y)))))

boxplot(split(x, cut(x,breaks = c(-Inf, 0, Inf))), names = make.italic(sNames))
```

which gives:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Thanks. I needed to get the expression outside the sapply function. To use without a custom function, `labels <- as.expression(lapply(sNames, function(x) bquote(italic(.(x)))))`

Answer (score 3):

Another simple solution is use par() to change the font of the axis.

```
df <- data.frame(x = rnorm(1000), labels = c(rep("One", 500), rep("Two", 500)))
par(font.axis = 3) # change font of the axis to italic
boxplot(x ~ labels, data = df, yaxt = "n")
par(font.axis = 1) # return to normal font (plain text)
axis(side = 2)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think I managed to obtain the desired results, but to be honest, I'm not really sure why it works, and therefore I'm not sure this solution is optimal:

```
x <- list(a=1:10, b=1:10)
foo <- Vectorize(function(u) eval(parse(text=sprintf("expression(italic(%s))", u))))
boxplot(x, names=foo(names(x)))
```

[image: Resulting labels]